# where does lpd and lpr log error and messages?

Tags: printing, openbsd, cups, smb, lp

Where can I find error and log messages from lpd and lpr?
I don't find any ouput when I run "lpr /tmp/test_file"

This terminates without any error.

I had looked for /etc/rc.d/lpd and it is failed. The issue was there is no /usr/sbin/lpd exists. There is only /usr/sbin/lpd.pre-cups

So I far I don't have any luck printing from lpr. On the other hand, using smbclient, I can easily print files.

I am thinking lpr tool is dead or near to stop development, but I don't know.

Can someone provide an alternative or a howto on using lpr?

I also tried CUPS from web interface. But the issue is I cannot use my smb credentials when using cups. It simply takes system user and gives no information.

OS: OpenBSD 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUPS replaces `lpd` and other commands, that's why you see some `*.pre-cups` files in `/usr/sbin`.

Usually `lpd` is configured via `/etc/printcap`, and more specifically logs will end up in the accounting file specified for each `printcap` entry with `lf=` (see `man 5 printcap`).  By default this is `/dev/console` but as you can see in `/etc/examples/printcap` this can be redirected to something like `/var/log/lpd-errs`.  CUPS also installs its own `printcap`.

On the other hand, CUPS logs are inside `/var/log/cups/`.  If you are running CUPS - which has nothing to do with `lpd` and will in fact replace it when installed - that's where your logs will be in.

If you want to use `lpd` instead of CUPS you'll need to uninstall the latter.  Depending on your printer to use `lpd` you'll probably need foomatic as well which is available in packages (see the package documentation for installation details).

Also, note that whether you use `lpd` or CUPS some printers also require a proprietary filter (e.g. EPSON's `escpr`) which very likely will have to be compiled from source.